# What conditions would make a system of two quadratic equations have one real solution?

Tags: quadratics, graphing-functions, quadratic-forms

The equation we use is in the form, $ax^2+bx+c= 0$. We also use the vertex form $a(x-p)^2+q$.
In the textbook, it says the two parabolas need to have the same vertex, but different a values. However, I also graphed examples where the vertex is different but the a value is the same. So they only intersect once and the two graphs are parallel.

Comment: For your problem, what exactly constitutes a system of two quadratic equations? Is it in one variable? Two? Are the equations of the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$, or $ax^2+bx+c=0$, or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have have $y = f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ [1], a solution will satisfy $f(x)-g(x)=0$, hence we need $f(x)-g(x)$ to have exactly one solution. Quadratic equations always have exactly two solutions, so either $f(x)-g(x)$ is linear, or it has a multiple root. If it's linear, it has the form $y = mx+B$ for some $m,B$ (I'm using a capital $B$ to distinguish it from the $b$ in $y = ax^+bx+x$), which means that the $a$ for $f$ and $g$ are the same, but their $b$ are different (if their $b$ are the same, $f(x)-g(x)$ would be constant, and so would have infinite solutions). If it has a multiple root, then it's of the form $y = A(x-r)^2$ for some $A,r$, which means that the $q$ and $p$ for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same.

[1] $x = y^2$ can also be considered a quadratic equation, but I'm assuming you're dealing with equations of the form $y = f(x)$.